# How to make dataflow apache beam job faster

Tags: mapreduce, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a apache beam job which takes around 6+ hours to complete. We ingest around 2.7Tb of GCS data along with other data sources like Bigtable/Bq/etc and then do a CoGroupbyKey.create().

The GCS data is in form of raw strings like `userId, hashedPhoneNumber` for e.g.:

```
525135a7-cb59-46ec-8d1d-0f12df02f486, 3070816492067005070
```

I have multiple DoFns when ingesting data from GCS and using GroupbyKey to create a KV of

```
uuid -> Set<hashedphoneNumber>
```

My questions are more towards how to make the pipeline faster?

1. Right now i read them both as strings data type. Will reading them as UUID and Long help? I wasnt able to get a UUID Coder when I was trying to do the test.
2. Making a Set<> does it cost extra? In general any serialization/deserialization should one keep in mind? Instead of making a Set can i just concat all hashedPhoneNumber and pass it down? Using Set<> helps me as a developer in understanding the pipeline i/p, o/p.
3. Any other way to make pipeline faster or general advices on how to use the types?

Comment: I suggest you to check the [Tips and tricks to get your Cloud Dataflow pipelines into production](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/tips-and-tricks-to-get-your-cloud-dataflow-pipelines-into-production), also to make fast your pipelines you could use the [autoscaling options](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#autoscaling) or  the feature called [Streaming Engine](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#streaming-engine), it's important to consider the charges this could generate.

Comment: The cost of the pipeline will depends of (vCPU, Memory and Storage: Persistent Disk) if  Set<> consumes more memory or vCPU this could impact the final price of your pipeline. You can verify how Dataflow pricing works [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pricing).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Coder section of this answer:

[Apache Beam - What are the key concepts for writing efficient data processing pipelines I should be aware of?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041925/apache-beam-what-are-the-key-concepts-for-writing-efficient-data-processing-pi/58054759#58054759)

There are other general tips and tricks there as well.